# Need to cut runtime finding divisor of given number

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime, modulo

I currently having problem of time limit exceeded for a problem in HackerRank, the problem state to sum all odd divisor of given number. This is my code:

```
int[] numbers = {21, 11, 7};

    long total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= numbers[i]; j+=2) {
            if (numbers[i] % j == 0) {
                total += (long) j;
            }
        }
    }
```

int[] numbers is variable that can contains thousands of numbers. I appreciate for any help.

```
int[] numbers = {
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7,
        21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7, 21, 11, 7};
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat I think inner loop of j will always giving odd number, isnt it?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This code running as expected, but it cannot pass of time limit when there is thousands of number in array.

Comment: You should memoize the results.

Comment: @saka1029 since there is various test case of input, I think memoization will not work.

Comment: @PutraPurba Memoization will work, I have added an example.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Memoization will work just in the case that OP mentioned above, where there is a huge number of number overlaps. It will not work at all if, for example, the test case is all the numbers from [1..10^6] appearing only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can speed up your code to only find the divisors for the first `sqrt(n)` numbers. Notice that if i divides N, you also get N/i as the other part of the divisor and the biggest i that you will ever need to check is sqrt(n).

sample code:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int n : all the numbers){
    for(int i = 1; i*i<=n;i++){
        if(n%i == 0){
            if(i % 2 == 1)sum+=i;
            if((n/i) % 2 == 1)sum += (n/i);
        }
    }
}
return sum;
```

Comment: Thanks! this code reducing runtime by 30%, now it passing the time limit :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to decrease runtime would be to only iterate to 1/2 of the number that you are currently finding the odd divisors for. It would look something like this:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= numbers[i]/2; j+=2) {
    if (numbers[i] % j == 0) {
        total += (long) j;
    }
}
```

You don't need to check beyond this halfway point, as a number above that cannot be a divisor of that number.

Comment: I have implement it too anyway and no significant change of runtime, it still showing about 180000 nanotime

Comment: How big are the numbers that you're dealing with?

Comment: It is always `numbers[i] % numbers[i] == 0`,  So you should add `total += numbers[i]` at first or last of the loop.

Comment: I've edited my question included, numbers in array, you can try print nanotime().